# Plotting data with matplotlib takes forever & plot crashes with higher number of samples

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot

got an issue with plotting x,y data. x is the time series, y the value as y(x). Data3.txt is a text file simply containing all the data with no headers in a matrix with 20 columns and 65534 rows.

Here is the code

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = []

with open('Data3.txt') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in csvReader:
        dates.append(row)

np.array(map(float, dates))

time=[]
value=[]
samples=8000

for row in dates:
    time.append(row[0])
    value.append(row[1])

print(len(time))

print(len(time[:samples]))

plt.plot(time[:samples], value[:samples])
plt.ylim(0,40)
plt.xlim(0,1200)
plt.show()
```

The plot is shown until I set samples to 7000 - see attached Figure_1. As soon as I set samples to 8000 it takes a lot longer to plot & the outcome is Figure_2.

```
print(len(time))
```

gives 65543

```
print(len(time[:samples]))
```

gives 8000

Really confused by that. Can anyone explain where this error might come from? Any hint concerning a smarter way of plotting is much appreciated, as well. I would now align every column one listname & make the plots.

[image: Figure_1]

[image: Figure_2]

Comment: Not sure what's happening, but using `append` for large arrays is definitely not a good idea.  Try using numpy everywhere `dates = np.array(dates, dtype=np.float)` and `time = dates[:,0]`; `value= dates[:,1]`

Comment: I suspect you are creating 8k separate lines. Note sure on the dimensionality of your data but the amount of x-values in your figures are nothing to be worried about. Your post however is a bit unclear on the details